# Get Document ID from Firebase Query using Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

If I have a collection called `userNames` and I use a firebase query to search for a document that a database field `uid` matches the current user ID, how do I print the document ID of the documents that contain that term?
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A query can return multiple documents that match the given condition and returns a [QuerySnapshot](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/QuerySnapshot-class.html) (that contains zero or many [DocumentSnapshots](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentSnapshot-class.html)).

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
  .collection('userNames')
  .where('uid', isEqualTo: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
  .get()
  .then((value) {
    value.docs.forEach((element) {
      print(element.id);
    });
  });
```

Here `value.docs` is a list of all the documents included in this snapshot and each of them has `id` property (the document ID).